# Is there an efficient in-place algorithm to separate an array into left and right by a given condition?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, bit-manipulation

It's pretty common to want to separate an array into a pair of arrays, one side pass and another side fail. The basic algorithm goes something like this:

```
function partition(list, cond) {
    let left = [];
    let right = [];

    for (let item of list) {
        if (cond(item)) {
            left.push(item);
        } else {
            right.push(item);
        }
    }

    return [left, right];
}
```

In my case, that condition is a bit more specialized - it's just an equal-length bitset where for each position, set = left, unset = right:

```
function partition(list, bitset) {
    let left = [];
    let right = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if ((bitset[i >>> 5] & 1 << (i & 31)) !== 0) {
            left.push(list[i]);
        } else {
            right.push(list[i]);
        }
    }

    return [left, right];
}
```

Thing is, I want to do this in-place and just have those where the corresponding bit in the bitset is `true` to the left, those where it's `false` to the right in the same array. (The entries do need to retain their order - it's important. Otherwise, it'd be pretty obvious.) This is the most efficient version I've come up with so far:

```
// The return value is the start offset for the rejects
function partition(list, cond) {
    let right = [];
    let rightStart = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if ((bitset[i >>> 5] & 1 << (i & 31)) !== 0) {
            list[rightStart++] = list[i];
        } else {
            right.push(list[i]);
        }
    }

    for (let i = 0, j = rightStart; i < list.length; i++) {
        list[j] = right[i];
    }

    return right_start;
}
```

Is it possible to do this with only O(1) space while still keeping it O(*n*) time, and if so, what would that algorithm look like?

Comment: @Emma I meant O(1) space and O(n) time, just forgot to explicitly state "time". Edited it to fix that.

Comment: Why is O(1) space a requirement? I can think of a solution using an int array for the positions which could be considerably less than the space required by a single list item but would technically still be O(n) space. For O(n) and O(1) I still don’t have an idea.

Comment: I seriously doubt that. The [stable partition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition) algorithm, which is what you are after, in constant space runs in `O(n log n)` time. The link talks C++, but the language does not matter here.

Comment: @user58697, I would post that as an answer. It is solid.

Comment: @trincot Thank you, done.

Comment: [This paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01994842) describes an in-place partitioning algorithm with O(n) time and O(1) space complexity.

Comment: @Socowi Interesting, and I found a preprint after searching. That's literally what I was looking for. Mind posting it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Sure. I planned to write an answer explaining the actual algorithm once I had time to read the paper in detail. But since the link is sufficient for you, I added it as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62442928/6770384) (which may be extended later on).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paper ...

Katajainen, J., Pasanen, T. Stable minimum space partitioning in linear time. BIT 32, 580–585 (1992).
https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01994842

... presents an algorithm for stable in-place partitioning in O(n) time and O(1) extra space.

Comment: For those without access to *BIT Numerical Mathematics*, the first author has a non-paywalled PDF of it on his department web page: http://hjemmesider.diku.dk/~jyrki/Paper/KP1992bJ.pdf

Comment: @Socowi if you have time, could you please extend the answer with the code/pseudo-code of this algorithm. It would be a great help for me (and possibly many others given the number of questions on this topic). The paper is a little too technical for me to understand.

Comment: @Mathphile I already started starting reading the papers and implementing the algorithm  (or rather algorithm*s*, as the solution is a combination of three other algorithms) in summer 2020. However, it is far too complex and long for a StackOverflow answer, so I dropped that project. I'd also advise against using the algorithm. It is nice for learning, but I think in nearly every real life scenario O(1) space isn't that important. Memory is cheap these days and I'd guess even merge sort on disk (instead of memory) is faster.

Comment: @Socowi thanks for replying. Can you confirm that the algorithm is actually stable, O(n)  time complexity, and O(1) auxiliary space complexity. I am a little doubtful if the paper is actually correct and don't want to drop heaps of time trying to implement the algorithm only to find out that it was wrong. Also I am not going to be using this algorithm for any real life scenario. My aim is to only implement this algorithm and post it somewhere for others who are interested in this but don't have the time to implement it themselves.

Comment: @Mathphile Yes, the authors claim *»O(n) data moves and O(1) extra space«*, the paper got accepted, and I couldn't find any errors either. But keep in mind that, just like always, O(1) *space* means actually O(1) memory cells (e.g. ints) of which each has at least log n bits. Normally we think in number of memory cells, therefore the part *»log n bits«* threw me off at first. But thinking about it, just accessing an array index needs log n *bits*, therefore a *real* is constant space (as in number of bits) algorithm for nearly anything is impossible.

Comment: @Socowi I have a few more questions about this algorithm. I would really appreciate if you could join this chatroom for a little discussion about it: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227510/sorting-algorithm

Comment: @Socowi Hello, I apologize for asking this after so long out of the blue (I was a bit too busy for some time). I have a few more concerns about the algorithm. I would really appreciate it if you could join this chatroom to discuss them. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229129/sorting-algorithm

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm you are looking for is known as stable partition. In constant space it has `O(n log n)` time complexity. See for example [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition) (it talks C++, but in this context it doesn't matter).

An implementation may look along the lines of

```
stable_partition(begin, end, predicate)
    if (end - begin == 0)
        return begin
    if (end - begin == 1)
        return predicate(*begin)? begin: end

    mid = begin + (end - begin)/2
    left_partition_point = stable_partition(begin, mid, predicate)
    right_partition_point = stable_partition(mid, end, predicate)
    return rotate(left_partition_point, mid, right_partition_point)
```

where `rotate` returns a position at which the leftmost element landed.

Comment: Are you sure this has constant space complexity? The implementation shown here is recursive and therefore requires additional space with each level of nesting. I think the space complexity should be *O(log n)* strictly speaking.